# Javax / Jersey Service Post - Consume Json Array

Tags: android, rest, jersey

I wrote a Javax / Jersey Service. I have problems with my @POST Method to consume an arrayList parsed in Json. I cannot imagine why this is not working. Just nothing happens. No Error - nothing. If I do the same with a single object it works fine.

**More information about my setting**:

```
jsersey-bundle-1.9.jar
asm-3.1.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.jar

set up the server with jesersy's httpserver
```

**First my App which do the post:**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

String json = "";
Ding obj1 = new Ding("Sebastian", 3456, 93);
Ding obj2 = new Ding("adsasd", 12, 1);

List<Ding> list = new ArrayList<Ding>();
list.add(obj1);
list.add(obj2);

Gson gson = new Gson();
json = gson.toJson(list);
Log.d("", json);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

httpPost.setEntity(se);

httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
result = read(inputStream);
```

**The json string looks like:**

```
[{"name":"Sebastian","grosse":93,"gewicht":3456},{"name":"adsasd","grosse":1,"gewicht":12}]
```

**The POST-Method which should receive the array:**
If I replace the `List<Ding> ding1` with `Ding ding` everything works fine. But with the arraylist nothing happens. Even no Error.

```
  @POST
  @Path( "putArray")
  @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
  @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
  public List<Ding> putDingArray( List<Ding> ding1){
      System.out.println("Los gehts: ");

      for(int i = 0; i < ding1.size(); i++){
          System.out.println(ding1.get(i).getName());
          System.out.println(ding1.get(i).getGewicht());
          System.out.println(ding1.get(i).getGrosse());

      }  
      return ding1;
  }
```

**The class Ding excluding filled constructer and getter/setter**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Ding {


    private int gewicht;
    private int grosse;
    private String name;

    public Ding(){

    }......
```

additional questions:

is POST the right way? Maybe Put?
Is it not common to transfer arraylist? I can not find something helpfull on google...
Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no solution yet but a workaround which is pretty well.

Instead of sending an ArrayList you can create a new object which holds the list...

```
public class DingHolder{

    private ArrayList<Ding> list = new ArrayList<Ding>();

    ... //getter setter constructor
```

Then you can insert as many ArrayLists you want and even give some attributes with this message... Better solution in any ways.